# Add a line break to the yahoo mailto client body

Tags: javascript, mailto

I have used %0D%0A to keep a line breaks in the mail body.
For gmail it works fine, but for yahoo its not working.

gmail link

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?view=cm&fs=1&to&su=test&body=Hi+%0D%0A+its+a+test+mail&bcc
```

yahoo link

```
http://compose.mail.yahoo.com/?to=&subject=test&body=Hi%0D%0Aits a test mail
```

Comment: How do you actually send the mail? Like `<a href="mailto:some@one.com">`? Could you please provide this code?

Comment: @elementzero23 I am sending the mail by opening a new browser window using the link in javascript

Comment: have you considered sending the mail via a server-side script? For example PHP? I am not sure whether this is an appropriate way to send mails programmatically

Comment: @elementzero23 yes, I am using my own API to send email as well, But in that case sender always be the email that I am using. Here I want to allow user to select their preferred mail client.